How to make migration after pulling database using Prisma.js without resetting data?
i tried to make migration using Prisma and mysql
npx prisma migrate dev --create-only

but the it need to reset the database, i don't want to lose my data. then i tried to make migration manually.
here's what i've done
npx prisma db pull
npx prisma generate
npx prisma migrate resolve --applied 0_init

it marked as applied but my migration.sql is empty
i want to make migration so my prisma and database working normally.

If your new Prisma schema changes drastically modify the underlying database structure, then you need to reset the database, because there would be no way to reconcile the old and new states of your database without a hard reset.
This is why Prisma Migrate allows you to seed your initial database after a migration so that you have an initial set of data to work with immediately after it is reset. If you need to get your development database to a good working state locally every time you reset it, seeding it with Prisma is the best way to do so.
